# Cocos2d-X 3 Memory Management

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am currently migrating I game I made in Cocos2d-X 2.2.6 to the latest version: Cocos2d-X 3.10, however I have a question about the memory management: I have created a lot of my own classes that inherit from CCObject (I have used a lot of XX::create(),  xx->retain() and xx->release() methods to create and destroy objects), however since this class has been deprecated, what should I use in its place?

I guess my question is how can I do the memory management of a custom class in Cocos2d-X version 3?

Comment: Inherit from `cocos2d::Ref`

Comment: it's best you read this answer it should help: 
http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/i-have-a-question-about-ref-class/28123/2

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing cocos2d-x games now.

As Mr.Zen commented, your class should inherit from cocos2d::Ref.

And member variables, use cocos2d::RefPtr.
It makes memory management easier, manages reference count automatically.
You don't need to worry about retain or release after the instance created.

Here is the snippet.

```
Sample.h
class Sample : public cocos2d::Ref
{
public:
    Sample();
    ~Sample();

    void hoge();
}

UseSample.h
class UseSample : public cocos2d::Ref
{
private:
    cocos2d::RefPtr<Sample> sample { nullptr };

    void createSample();
    void useSample();
}

UseSample.cpp
void UseSample::createSample()
{
    this->sample = Sample::create(); // RefPtr increases sample retain count;
}

void UseSample::useSample()
{
    this->sample->hoge();
}
```

Hope this can helps.